# How to run a subreport multiple times in one report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, instance, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to have a subreport run for every instance in a parameter list? My subreport is designed to only take one parameter, I just want to have the subreport returned multiple times in one report.

Comment: if the subreport takes in multi value parameters it should be running once for each value you are inputing.

Comment: the problem is my subreport only takes one parameter.  i cant get it to work right making the subreport multivalued, so i was going to embed the subreport in a larger report and hopefully iterate

Comment: Whats the error when you try to make it multi valued?

Comment: Because of how my report is laid out, it tries to stuff all the relevant information for all instances of parameters into one spot on one report, instead of a per parameter basis

Comment: let me know if you need more context/don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "tablefy" your parameter list :

1. Create a query that will `un-pivot` your param list as a TABLE(INT).
   EX:

   ```
   SELECT IDField FROM
    dbo.TableValueFunctionToSplitCommaDelimitedListIntoTableOfInts(@MultiValueListParam)
   ```
2. Add a table or matrix your report.
3. Add a DataSet and set the result to the sp or query created in step 1.
4. Set the DataSet of the table in step 2 to the DataSet created in step 3.
5. Insert the SubReport into the detail of the new table.

This should print once per detail band. You can set the parameter to `Fields!IDValue.Value`